# Shuffle all rows of a csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv, random, shuffle

I have an input csv file with data:

```
a   15
b   14
c   20
d   45
```

I want to generate a different csv file which will contain complete data rows from input file but rows should be shuffled.

like output file may contain values-

```
b 14
a 15
c 20
d 45
```

I have tried this code:

```
import random
import sys
op=open('random.csv','w+')
ip=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
data=ip.read()
data1=str(random.choices(data))
op.write(data1)
op.close()
```

Answer (score 17):

Another shot using `pandas`. You can read your .csv file with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', header=None)
```

and then using `df.sample` to shuffle your rows. This will return a random sample of your dataframe with rows shuffled. Using `frac=1` you consider the whole set as sample:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   0   1
0  a  15
1  b  14
2  c  20
3  d  45

In [19]: ds = df.sample(frac=1)

In [20]: ds
Out[20]: 
   0   1
1  b  14
3  d  45
0  a  15
2  c  20
```

If you need to save out again the new shuffled file you can just:

```
ds.to_csv('newfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function from Python [random](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) module. Like this:

```
import random
fid = open("example.txt", "r")
li = fid.readlines()
fid.close()
print(li)

random.shuffle(li)
print(li)

fid = open("shuffled_example.txt", "w")
fid.writelines(li)
fid.close()
```

The print commands result in this:

```
['b 14\n', 'a 15\n', 'c 20\n', 'd 45\n']
['d 45\n', 'a 15\n', 'b 14\n', 'c 20\n']
```

And the new file is this:

```
d 45
a 15
b 14
c 20
```

Just make sure you have a newline at the end of each of your original lines.

Comment: tried this, getting error 'None Type, object is not iterable' code- ip=open(sys.argv[1],'r') data=ip.readlines() ip.close() data1=shuffle(data) op=open('random.csv','w+') op.writelines(data1) op.close()

Comment: @RoshVerma I've run the code before posting so I'm guessing its something in your data that is causing the problem. Try to print both `data` and `data1` and tell me the results.

Comment: Yes, got the error, it was in my code. Thanks a lot for your help. It worked finally. :)

Comment: but CSV file can contain line endings in quotas. You cannot just shuffle lines, you need to shuffle CSV rows...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [shuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html).

Once you installed `shuf`, run

```
shuf -o shuffled-file.csv < file-to-shuffle.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think it is always useful to have your random seed in your control and the link https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources explained a simple example how you can do this.

Answer (score 3):

If your CSV contains headers then you can shuffle it using pandas like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name) # avoid header=None. 
shuffled_df = df.sample(frac=1)
shuffled_df.to_csv(new_file_name, index=False)
```

This way you can avoid shuffling headers and remove index from your new CSV.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function in the random module. Also, you can you `readlines()` in order to have a list:

```
>>> ip=open('random.csv','r')
>>> data=ip.readlines()
>>> data
['a   15\n', 'b   14\n', 'c   20\n', 'd   45\n']
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(data)
>>> data
['c   20\n', 'd   45\n', 'a   15\n', 'b   14\n']
```

If you have an header, just split the data, and shuffle the rows:

```
>>> ip=open('random.csv','r')
>>> data=ip.readlines()
>>> header, rest=data[0], data[1:]
>>> header
'h1  h2\n'
>>> rest
['a   15\n', 'b   14\n', 'c   20\n', 'd   45\n']
>>> shuffle(rest)
>>> rest
['c   20\n', 'd   45\n', 'a   15\n', 'b   14\n']
>>> [header]+rest
['h1  h2\n', 'c   20\n', 'd   45\n', 'a   15\n', 'b   14\n']
```

Using with statement:

```
>>> with open('random.csv','r') as ip:
...   data=ip.readlines()
...
>>> header, rest=data[0], data[1:]
>>> shuffle(rest)
>>> with open('output.csv','w') as out:
...   out.write(''.join([header]+rest))
...
>>>
~$ cat output.csv
h1  h2
d   45
b   14
a   15
c   20
```

Comment: tried this, getting error 'None Type, object is not iterable' code- ip=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
data=ip.readlines()
ip.close()
data1=shuffle(data)
op=open('random.csv','w+')
op.writelines(data1)
op.close()

Comment: @RoshVerma shuffle modifies the list inplace. No need to do `data1=shuffle(data)`. Also you should check the [with statement](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Damn! Bang on. Man you are good. It worked. I had been trying this for 2  days. Thanks a tonn.

Comment: Just, one more thing if you can answer. If my data has header, is it possible to keep it at row[0] and shuffle the rest of data.

Comment: Sorry for the previous link : [with statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, your code worked perfectly as I required. Thanks a lot. Except I couldn't understand 2 things.

Comment: 1. You just wrote header. Is it a variable you declared and how header assigned itself data[0] and y while joining it is in []. 2. rest has first row of data means header yet it is shuffling? I am a little confused actually. I am sorry I am just a beginner if you could explain.

Comment: `header, rest=data[0], data[1:]` could be write as `header=data[0]` + `rest=data[1:]`, so header is a variable containing the first elem of the data list: so it's a string, and rest is a list containing all of data, except the first element.

Comment: Thank you very much. Understood it completely. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read the actual lines of the file.

```
ip.readlines()
```

And `random.shuffle()` should be used to swap around the lines.

At the moment, you read an entire string and I think only randomly get a single character from the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code according to @cricket answer:

```
from random import shuffle

with open('input.csv','r') as f1:
    data=f1.readlines()

shuffle(data[0])

with open('output.csv','w') as f2:
    f2.write(''.join([data[1:]] + data[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow this way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file.csv", header=0)    
df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
```